# Is there a way to generate a X.509 Certificate in Swift programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, security, x509

I know this is an old topic, since the very few answers found on the internet are 5 - 8 years old.

My requirement is straightforward: I have generated an asymmetric key pair, and I want to send the **public key** to the server embedded in a X.509 Certificate (or **SecCertificate**, using Apple's terminology), signed eventually with the **private key**.

I try to avoid the OpenSSL library since Apple highly discourages doing so. Are there any alternatives?

Some of the tried solutions:

- https://github.com/henrinormak/Heimdall
- http://digitalleaves.com/blog/2015/10/sharing-public-keys-between-ios-and-the-rest-of-the-world/

Comment: If it is not part of new Swift Crypto (looks like no Swift wrapper for it yet?), you should create an issue: https://github.com/apple/swift-crypto